# Add a list header to cognos report studio list

Tags: cognos

In cognos 10 report studio, I have  a list. Is there a way to add a list header? I can see how to add a list page header, but  I am looking for a list header. In my toolbox, I cannot see a 'list header'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Page Structure</kbd>. Select `List`, you want to add list header and on `Column Titles Properties` change it to `At Start of Details` and `Add List Header` to the List from <kbd>Structure</kbd> > <kbd>Header and Footers</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do a header is probably to put in a table with a column and two rows for each list on the page. Drag the list into the bottom row and then put a text item in the top with whatever you want the header to say. Also, if you have multiple lists on the page, adding in an extra column between them makes the formatting a bit neater if you're using Excel for your output.